# propagating values over non-unique (duplicate) cells in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

I have the following dataframe

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame({'Players': [ 'Sam', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Sam',
                 'Jill', 'Bill', 'Nod', 'Mallory', 'Ping', 'Lamar'],
                 'Address': ['112 Fake St','13 Crest St','14 Main St','112 Fake St','2 Morningwood','7 Cotton Dr','14 Main St','20 Main St','7 Cotton Dr','7 Cotton Dr'],
                 'Status': ['Infected','','Dead','','','','','','','Infected'],
                 })

print(df)
```

and I want to propagate the Status value 'infected' to everyone inside the same Address.

This means if more than one person is in the same address and one person has the status infected then everyone will have this status.

So the result would look like this:

```
df2=pd.DataFrame({'Players': [ 'Sam', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Sam',
                 'Jill', 'Bill', 'Nod', 'Mallory', 'Ping', 'Lamar'],
                 'Address': ['112 Fake St','13 Crest St','14 Main St','112 Fake St','2 Morningwood','7 Cotton Dr','14 Main St','20 Main St','7 Cotton Dr','7 Cotton Dr'],
                 'Status': ['Infected','','Dead','Infected','','Infected','','','Infected','Infected'],
                 })

print(df2)
```

How would I do this? So far I tried this:

```
df[df.duplicated("Address")]
```

But it only selects the later duplicates not all of them

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one method:

```
In [19]:    
infected = df[df['Status']=='Infected'].set_index('Address')
df.loc[df['Address'].isin(infected.index),'Status'] = df['Address'].map(infected['Status']).fillna('')
df

Out[19]:
         Address  Players    Status
0    112 Fake St      Sam  Infected
1    13 Crest St     Greg          
2     14 Main St    Steve      Dead
3    112 Fake St      Sam  Infected
4  2 Morningwood     Jill          
5    7 Cotton Dr     Bill  Infected
6     14 Main St      Nod          
7     20 Main St  Mallory          
8    7 Cotton Dr     Ping  Infected
9    7 Cotton Dr    Lamar  Infected
```

So this first constructs a view of your df where the status is 'Infected', we then set the index to the address, this creates a lookup table where we can then lookup the address using [`map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html#pandas.Series.map) in the `infected` index and return the status.

I use `loc` here to only select the addresses that are in the infected index, to leave the other rows untouched.