# Python Pandas Adding conditions on cells with duplicate values

Tags: python, pandas, group-by

This is a followup to my previous question [propagating values over non-unique (duplicate) cells in pandas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30445883/propagating-values-over-non-unique-duplicate-cells-in-pandas)

I have a DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'First': ['Sam', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Sam',
                             'Jill', 'Bill', 'Nod', 'Mallory', 'Ping', 'Lamar'],
                   'Last': ['Stevens', 'Hamcunning', 'Strange', 'Stevens',
                            'Vargas', 'Simon', 'Purple', 'Green', 'Simon', 'Simon'],
                   'Address': ['112 Fake St',
                               '13 Crest St',
                               '14 Main St',
                               '112 Fake St',
                               '2 Morningwood',
                               '7 Cotton Dr',
                               '14 Main St',
                               '20 Main St',
                               '7 Cotton Dr',
                               '7 Cotton Dr'],
                   'Status': ['Infected', '', 'Infected', '', '', '', '','', '', 'Infected'],
                   'Level': [10, 2, 7, 5, 2, 10, 10, 20, 1, 1],
                   })
```

And lets say this time I want propagate the Status value 'infected' to everyone inside the same Address with an additional condition such as if they have the same value in Last.
So the result would look like:

```
df2 = df1.copy(deep=True)
df2['Status'] = ['Infected', '', 'Infected', 'Infected', '', 'Infected', '', '', 'Infected', 'Infected']
```

What if I wanted the individual to be marked infected if he in the same address but not the same level? The results would be:

```
df3 = df1.copy(deep=True)
df3['Status'] = ['Infected', '', 'Infected', '', '', 'Infected', '', '', '', 'Infected']
```

How would I do this? Is this a groupby problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Same address" is expressed by "groupby".

```
import pandas as pd


df=pd.DataFrame({'First': [ 'Sam', 'Greg', 'Steve', 'Sam',
                 'Jill', 'Bill', 'Nod', 'Mallory', 'Ping', 'Lamar'],
                 'Last': [ 'Stevens', 'Hamcunning', 'Strange', 'Stevens',
                 'Vargas', 'Simon', 'Purple', 'Green', 'Simon', 'Simon'],
                 'Address': ['112 Fake St','13 Crest St','14 Main St','112 Fake St','2 Morningwood','7 Cotton Dr','14 Main St','20 Main St','7 Cotton Dr','7 Cotton Dr'],
                 'Status': ['Infected','','Infected','','','','','','','Infected'],
                 'Level': [10,2,7,5,2,10,10,20,1,1],
                 })

df2_index = df.groupby(['Address', 'Last']).filter(lambda x: (x['Status'] == 'Infected').any()).index
df2 = df.copy()
df2.loc[df2_index, 'Status'] = 'Infected'

df3_status = df.groupby('Address', as_index=False, group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: pd.Series(list('Infected' if (row['Status'] == 'Infected') or ((x['Status'] == 'Infected') & (x['Level'] != row['Level'])).any() else '' for _, row in x.iterrows()), index=x.index))
df3 = df.copy()
df3['Status'] = df3_status
```

Comment: @ccsv Can you be more clear what df3 is about? My code mark infected follow 2 rules: 1. already infected 2. someone with same address but different level is infected

Comment: The column `df3['Status']` is all blank when I ran the code.

Comment: @ccsv that's weird, I test it by using `%paste` of ipython, and result is not all blank.

Comment: Ok If found the error I declared `df3` somewhere else and did not fill it sorry.